# Two jumbotron within a row with text aligned center

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

i ma having trouble to play with boostrap 4 css.

I would like to have in a row two jumbotron with the same height no matter what is inside and with the inside of the div vertically aligned center.

my code is the following :

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="row">
          <div class="col-8">
              <div class="jumbotron greenback">
                   <h7>Welcome to the Project test Detail page</h7>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-4">
              <div class="jumbotron greenback">
                  <div class="inner-score">
                      <div class="score-title">
                          <h6>Team Score</h6>
                      </div>
                      <div class="score-value">
                           <h4>85</h4>
                      </div>    
                  </div>

              </div>

          </div>
      </div>      
</div>
```

I created a jsfidlle to show you https://jsfiddle.net/kscv67kt/2/
As you can see now the two jumbotron have vertical text align center but are not full row height..

Comment: Your fiddle is empty

Comment: could you try again?

Comment: Still empty, ill post an answer now so you can follow it. Bootstrap Jumbotron with same heigth nomatter length inside

Comment: Hi thx for your answer I am trying right now to implement it. I updated my js it should work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make Bootstrap columns all the same height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height)

Comment: hi Rob it is a semi duplicate because I manage to set the same height but the text is not vertically centered ( I ma talking about the answer bootstrap4)

Comment: and my problem is not about same col height but the jumbotron height

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried adding `height: 100%` to the jumbotron elements?

```
.jumbotron.greenback {
  height: 100%;
}
```

This will cause both elements to fill the height of the container (the `.row` in this case).

Worth noting that setting `height: 100%` would cause the element's bottom margin to overflow it's container, so for neatness you could adjust the jumbotron's and their container's margin-bottom properties accordingly...

```
.container {
  margin-bottom: 32px /* Moving the margin-bottom value of the 
  .jumbotron to it's outer container.  */
}

.jumbotron.greenback {
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Alternatively with jQuery...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var jumboMaxHeight = 0

  $(".jumbotron").each(function(){
    if ($(this).height() > jumboMaxHeight) { 
      jumboMaxHeight = $(this).height() }
    })

  $(".jumbotron").height(jumboMaxHeight)

})
```

Edit: To centre the text elements within the `.jumbotron`, there are a number of ways you could do it, one is using `flexbox` properties on the parent element (in conjunction with the jQuery solution)...

```
.jumbotron.greenback {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

Comment: Hi thx you for your answer .. I guess jquery is the best options.. the thing the alignment vertical of the text is kind of messed up, have a look to the JS fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/kscv67kt/5/

Comment: No worries, I've updated the answer to add a suggestion for the vertical alignment issue.